# How can I remove all occurrences of a sub-multiset in Isabelle?

Tags: function, isabelle, proof, multiset

So I'd like to define a function (we'll call it `applied`) that would get rid of all occurrences of a sub-multiset within another multiset and replace each occurrence with a single element. For example,

`applied {#a,a,c,a,a,c#} ({#a,a,c#}, f) = {#f,f#}`

So at first I tried a definition:

```
definition applied :: "['a multiset, ('a multiset × 'a)] ⇒ 'a multiset" where
"applied ms t = (if (fst t) ⊆# ms then plus (ms - (fst t)) {#snd t#} else ms)"
```

However, I quickly realised that this would only remove one occurrence of the subset. So if we went by the previous example, we would have

`applied {#a,a,c,a,a,c#} ({#a,a,c#}, f) = {#f,a,a,c#}`

which is not ideal.

I then tried using a function (I initially tried primrec, and fun, but the former didn't like the structure of the inputs and fun couldn't prove that the function terminates.)

```
function applied :: "['a multiset, ('a multiset × 'a)] ⇒ 'a multiset" where
"applied ms t = (if (fst t) ⊆# ms then applied (plus (ms - (fst t)) {#snd t#}) t else ms)"
  by auto
termination by (*Not sure what to put here...*)
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to prove the termination of this function. I've tried using "termination", auto, fastforce, force, etc and even sledgehammer but I can't seem to find a proof for this function to work.

Could I please have some help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining it recursively like this is indeed a bit tricky because termination is not guaranteed. What if `fst t = {# snd t #}`, or more generally `snd t ∈# fst t`? Then your function keeps running in circles and never terminates.

The easiest way, in my opinion, would be a non-recursive definition that does a ‘one-off’ replacement:

```
definition applied :: "'a multiset ⇒ 'a multiset ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a multiset" where
  "applied ms xs y =
     (let n = Inf ((λx. count ms x div count xs x) ` set_mset xs)
      in ms - repeat_mset n xs + replicate_mset n y)"
```

I changed the tupled argument to a curried one because this is more usable for proofs in practice, in my experience – but tupled would of course work as well.

`n` is the number of times that `xs` occurs in the `ms`. You can look at what the other functions do by inspecting their definitions.

One could also be a bit more explicit about `n` and write it like this:

```
definition applied :: "'a multiset ⇒ 'a multiset ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a multiset" where
  "applied ms xs y =
     (let n = Sup {n. repeat_mset n xs ⊆# ms}
      in ms - repeat_mset n xs + replicate_mset n y)"
```

The drawback is that this definition is not executable anymore – but the two should be easy to prove equivalent.

Comment: Looks cool! May I know why the second one wouldn't be executable anymore?

Comment: Because it uses a set comprehension that is (a priori) unbounded. Also set comprehensions don't work well with executability even when they are bounded (one has to write it more explicitly using e.g. `Set.filter` so that the code generator can figure it out). One could probably fiddle around with it to restore executability, e.g. by writing the set as `Set.filter (λn. repeat n xs ⊆# ms) {..size ms}` or something like that, but it doesn't really make sense since the first version I posted above is simpler and more efficient.

Comment: A typical approach would be to e.g. define it as the second version and then prove that it is equal to the first version, and register that as a `[code]` equation so that it is executable.

Comment: That's interesting, is there a specific place I can read more about code equations?

Comment: There is the tutorial on code generation: https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/doc/codegen.pdf